# Google App Engine datastore for Go does not have != filter

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am messing with GAE for go recently and found it misses fundamental != (not equal to) filter in their datastore API.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Property_filters

It also has no "OR" condition operand.

Could anyone tell me how could I filter data which is not equal to something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

even the languages that DO have the "!=" filter actually break it down into two inequality filters (one > and one <).  Maybe doing the equivalent will solve your problem?

> select * from table where param != "test"

becomes equal to

> select * from table where param > "test"

merged with the results of

> select * from table where param < "test"

not ideal, but given the limitations of the platform... I think it's your only choice.

Comment: I think it is the only way at the moment. Since it lacks of 'OR' operand, i have to bootstrap two db queries to do this which is not good. As it lacks of those fundamental operands, I have to suggest not using GAE for Go projects.

Comment: @Keyang yeah well it IS still experimental.  I would personally wait until they make it more official :/

Comment: An important piece is that currently OR and != are implemented entirely in the client library by combining queries together. So if you implement your own OR operator it will work exactly like the ones that are "built in" to the libraries in other languages. I wouldn't let this influence which language you work in.

Comment: I am having the same issue in NodeJS. Since there is no 'OR' operator the results must be gathered in separate queries and then combined. Here's some details on how I achieved the 'OR' condition by re-inventing the wheel in NodeJS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437166/google-datastore-combine-union-multiple-sets-of-entity-results-to-achieve-or-c

Answer (score 3):

From the page you linked there's actually an example of how to do that kind of queries.

From [Restrictions on queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Restrictions_on_queries):

> **Inequality filters are limited to at most one property**
>
> > To avoid having to scan the entire index table, the query mechanism relies on all of a query's potential results being adjacent to one another in the index. To satisfy this constraint, a single query may not use inequality comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on more than one property across all of its filters. For example, the following query is valid, because both inequality filters apply to the same property:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Person").
        Filter("BirthYear >=", minBirthYear).
        Filter("BirthYear <=", maxBirthYear)
```

Comment: I think it tries to say the inequality filters, which are >,<,>=,<= can only be used on one property. I am asking how to do != on one property.

Comment: No, you do != by using `datastore.NewQuery("P").Filter("Prop >", key).Filter("Prop <", key)`. just like @Julldar's answer.

Comment: datastore.NewQuery("P").Filter("Prop >", key).Filter("Prop <", key) will retrieve data with Prop greater than key AND Prop less than key. aka, empty. Since multiple filters on same Query is connected as "AND" operand. See reference. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.Filter. As I mentioned, it does not have a "OR" operand so we cannot use this solution.