# Firestore in Datastore mode, query using OR

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, datastore

In the attempt of migrating to the new Datastore mode in Firestore from the former Datastore, and as well migrating from Python 2.7 to 3.7, we're trying to figure out how to query using OR operator!

Formally using the NDB library, there was `ndb.AND` & `ndb.OR` yet there is no mentioning of the OR in the new query structure in Python 3

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#filters), *query* happens on a few steps, and it is possible to add multiple filters on multiples *`add_filter`* steps:

```
query = client.query(kind='Task')
query.add_filter('done', '=', False)
query.add_filter('priority', '=', 4)
```

The above basically means:

> Task entities that are marked not done **AND** have a priority of 4

How about the **OR** operator?

What if one wants to query for a property that has this value **OR** this value?

Comment: Logical OR queries aren't supported by Firestore.

Comment: Interesting, what would be a clever way around this? All I can think of right now is
1) Re-model the property as an Array and add_filter for the values required? 
2) Another way might be to create query steps for first value and add fetch results to a list, then start another query steps and append results to the formally created list. Sounds like a bit of a slower process though :/

Comment: Notably, Firebase in Datastore mode migration should be non breaking (right?!) so old code using NDB for "OR", and also "IN" operator, should still work! any notes on that?

Comment: Perform each query individually, then merge the results on the client.  That's the standard advice.

Comment: Potentially of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437166/google-datastore-combine-union-multiple-sets-of-entity-results-to-achieve-or-c/47438039#47438039